# Why does following method not give syntax error?

Tags: typescript

```
// There are three possible booleans available this.oneBoolean, this.otherBoolean and this.thirdBoolean not used in the scope of this method
canEditSomething(): boolean {
   if(this.oneBoolean) {
     return true
    }
   if (this.otherBoolean) {
     return false
   }
}
```

So the question is if none of the if conditions are satisfied as above, does compiler or more precisely transpiler add default return statement at the end of the method scope before returning?

Comment: Yup, this function will return undefined if no condition matches

Comment: So it would return undefined and not false as a default boolean? That's interesting.

Comment: @steve_darwin `Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'` right from the Typescript playground

Comment: It errors with a flag `--strictNullChecks`

Comment: Understood Thanks @Thomas